# Hibernate - Session is closed

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, session

Googled a lot but didn't get any proper solution. I am trying to make a simple e-commerce website where I have to show a list of orders in admin panel but got stuck there. Error says '**Session is closed!**' but I have opened a session at the begging of method. Please someone tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
public List<OrderModel> getAllOrders() throws HibernateException {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        try {
            final String hql = "FROM OrderModel WHERE status=:status";
            Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
            query.setParameter("status", "0");

            return query.list();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            throw new HibernateException(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if(session.isOpen()){
                session.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Session is declared in parent class.

```
@Autowired
protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;
protected Session session;
protected Transaction trans;
```

Comment: Your `session` object is a class variable, which is not thread safe. Perhaps some other thread is closing the session? Try putting `session` inside the method like `Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();`. If it doesn't work, please post the stack trace and line numbers in your code.

Comment: Thanks! it help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying from the comment:-

Your `session` object is a class variable, which is not thread safe. Perhaps some other thread is closing the session? Try putting `session` inside the method like

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```

Also have a look at DAO pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace this `if(session.isOpen())` with `if(session == null || session.isOpen() == false)`